# Isolated edges in hyperbolic Delaunay triangulation

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, computational-geometry, tessellations

I have played with the C++ library CGAL to do some hyperbolic Delaunay triangulations. Sometimes (often) the triangulation has some isolated edges, as in this example:

[image]

Is it theoretically normal to get such edges? I googled but found nothing. It is said in the CGAL documentation that hyperbolic Delaunay triangulations are connected. If we consider that such edges belong to the triangulation then it is clearly not connected.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question but you might find useful information here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00164401

Comment: What do you mean by "normal"? If you mean "possible", then sure, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks @MoisheKohan. But how do you know that? And then how is it possible to say the triangulation is connected? As a side question, do you know whether there is a name for the isolated or non-isolated edges or vertices?

Comment: Some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72203195/1100107

Comment: I think I understand the connectedness now: this is the connectedness of the triangulation as a graph, not the connectedness in the topological sense.

Answer (score 1):

What you call an "isolated edge" is simply an edge which is not incident to any 2-dimensional face (such an edge is called a "[facet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facet_(geometry)#:%7E:text=A%20facet%20of%20a%20simplicial,the%20meaning%20from%20polyhedral%20combinatorics.)"). To see that such edges can exist, consider a finite subset of $H^2$ consisting of two distinct points. The corresponding Delaunay triangulation will consist of a single edge.  More generally, consider a finite subset of $H^2$ contained in a single geodesic. Then every edge of the  corresponding Delaunay triangulation will be "isolated." If you still do not liкe this example, then perturb it slightly: If the perturbation is small enough then every edge is still "isolated."

Comment: Thanks. But you don't mention the root cause, which has been told to me by a CGAL author on Stackoverflow. The root cause is that the CGAL authors choosed to get rid of the so-called non-compact triangles, i.e. the triangles whose circumcircle is not entirely contained in the Poincaré disk. Otherwise you can simply do an Euclidean Delaunay tessellation, this is the same as the hyperbolic one (as graphs) if you don't remove anything, and there's no isolated vertex in the Euclidean Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: My answer is about mathematics, not about somebody's computer program. I do not understand what they got rid of and it does not seem to be relevant since I simply use the definition.

Comment: Your answer is nice but here the cause is human, not mathematical. If my wording is not clear maybe you will understand with the CGAL documentation instead: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Hyperbolic_triangulation_2/index.html

Comment: Look at the picture I posted in my question. This "isolated" vertex is not aligned with two other vertices on a geodesic.

Comment: I no longer understand your question: The math question is answered, "human" questions are off-topic here. If you have questions about programming, MSE is not the right place for it.

Comment: This is not a human question. This question has form: "does this computer program respect the mathematical theory?" And there's no degenerate triangle in my picture, so your answer is not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given in [the CGAL documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Hyperbolic_triangulation_2/index.html). As noted by Moishe Kohan, the "isolated" edges can appear for example when the set of points consist of three points aligned on a hyperbolic line. But I said that these isolated edges **often** appear; I forgot to say that I took the points at random, and getting aligned random points do not often occur. Moreover this is not the situation of the picture I posted.

The reason is that the authors of CGAL consider that a triangle such as the shaded one below is not hyperbolic, because its circumcircle is not contained in the Poincaré disk:

[image]

And so CGAL discards such triangles from the Delaunay triangulation. I said to a CGAL author that this choice surprises me because mathematically speaking, this triangle is not less hyperbolic that another one. She replies that this is not about hyperbolicity, but about the Delaunay property (so the documentation is not very clear about this point).